# How to implement std::ops traits for multiple rhs

Tags: rust

If I have:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
struct Bytes(u64);

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
struct Seconds(f64);

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
struct BytesPerSecond(f64);
```

is there a simple way to get something like:

```
let b = Bytes(1024);
let s = Seconds(2.0);
let bytes = b / b; // yields Bytes
let bps = b / s; // yields BytesPerSecond
```

The `uom` crate lets you do things like:

```
let l1 = Length::new::<meter>(15.0);
let t1 = Time::new::<second>(50.0);
let l2 = l1 / l1
let v1 = l1 / t1;
```

Since each trait (`Div`, in this case) can only have one method, it seems like I would have to use generics to create multiple `impls`. I'm not sure how that would work in practice, though (and I found `uoms`'s source hard to decipher).

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "simple." Because it's generic over the right-hand side argument, you can manually implement `Div<Bytes, Output = Bytes>` as well as `Div<Seconds, Output = BytesPerSecond>` for `Bytes`.

Comment: Math nitpick: the result of bytes / bytes ought to be unitless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, `Div` is generic over the right-hand operand type. It simply defaults to `Self` if left unspecified (done via `Div<RhsType>`). And the output type must be supplied regardless.

So implementing `Bytes / Bytes = Bytes` and `Bytes / Seconds = BytesPerSecond` would look like this:

```
impl Div for Bytes {
    type Output = Bytes;

    fn div(self, rhs: Bytes) -> Bytes {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Div<Seconds> for Bytes {
    type Output = BytesPerSecond;

    fn div(self, rhs: Seconds) -> BytesPerSecond {
        todo!()
    }
}
```